# Denied permission at startup

Tags: android

I get an error when writing to a file 'Denied permisson write..' bur no i set 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storage permission error in Marshmallow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission comes under Dangerous permission category and from android 6.0 and above requires these permission to be asked at runtime.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

here is another good tutorial for the same:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/